# Is there any QUnit assertion/function who test whether element in array or not

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit

I have an array of my expected output in my Qunit function.Now I want to test that Is my result of function is in this array or not.

```
var a =new array('abc','cde','efg','mgh');
```

Now my question is Is there any QUnit assertion/function that can do this for me ??

I know that by some JS coding i create a method to check this but i wanna be spefic to OUnit only !!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have JavaScript 1.6 you can use [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
test("myFunction with expected value", function() {
    var expectedValues = ['abc','cde','efg','mgh'];
    ok(expectedValues.indexOf(myFunction()) !== -1, 'myFunction() should return an expected value');
});
```

If you want you can extend QUnit to support these kind of assertions:

```
QUnit.extend(QUnit, {
    inArray: function (actual, expectedValues, message) {
        ok(expectedValues.indexOf(actual) !== -1, message);
    }
});
```

Then you can use the this custom `inArray()` method in your tests:

```
test("myFunction with expected value", function() {
    var expectedValues = ['abc','cde','efg','mgh'];
    QUnit.inArray(myFunction(), expectedValues, 'myFunction() should return an expected value');
});
```

I created [a jsFiddle to show both options](http://jsfiddle.net/odi86/WBhZJ/).

Answer (score 0):

QUnit offers a deepEqual function for this.
You can compare array using it:

```
var resultArray = myFunction();
deepEqual(["Expected", "array"], resultArray, "myFunction returned wrong Array");
```